# How to add white space between two elements?

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I new to xml twig, how can I add space between two elements in xml-twig?

Input:

```
<xml>
<fig id="fig6_4">
<label><xref ref-type="page" id="page_54"/>[Figure 4]</label>
<caption>The Klein Sexual Orientation Grid</caption>
</fig>
</xml>
```

Script:

```
$xml_twig_content = XML::Twig->new(
                                   twig_handlers => {
                                   'fig' => \&figure,
},
                                  );
$xml_twig_content->parsefile('sample.xml');

sub figure{
my ($xml_twig_content, $figure) = @_;
my @figchild = $figure->children;
foreach my $chid (@figchild){
if ($chid->name =~ /label/){
        my $t = $chid->text;
        $chid->set_inner_xml($t . ' ');
        $chid->erase;
}
```

output:

```
<xml>
<fig id="fig6_4">
[Figure 4] <caption>The Klein Sexual Orientation Grid</caption>
</fig>
</xml>
```

i need:

```
<xml>
    <fig id="fig6_4">
    <xref ref-type="page" id="page_54"/>[Figure 4] <caption>The Klein Sexual Orientation Grid</caption>
    </fig>
    </xml>
```

how can i inset space between two elements.....

Comment: White space is not relevant in XML. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you are talking about indentation, have you looked at [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.42/Twig_pm.slow#SYNOPSIS)'s pretty_print option?

Comment: yes, not relevant but I need insert space between two elements. How can I insert space or add?

Comment: @Jack: Actually, whitespace is technically significant in XML (but not HTML). Sometimes it's useful to be able to store text with line breaks and tabs and have them survive a round trip :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a handler on `fig/label`, since that's the only element that needs to be modified. The code in the handler then needs to suffix the element with whitespace, then erase the tag:

```
XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 'fig/label' => sub { $_->suffix( ' ')->erase; }});
```

Comment: I'm definitely going to start using XML::Twig more now. That's remarkably elegant!

Comment: Thanks. The power, and curse, of XML::Twig is the enormous number of methods, that make it simple to do lots of things... if you can remember them.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me exactly what the goal is - your output data format doesn't *look* particularly desirable. Nonetheless the example below should be enough to get you on your way. It addresses two points:

1. That 'xref' is missing in your current output.
2. How to add arbitrary whitespace (basically PCDATA content) to a document

As a side note: I've not used XML::Twig before; the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) is actually pretty good if you are comfortable with XML concepts.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'fig' => \&figure
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
);

$twig->parse(do { local $/; <DATA> });

$twig->print;

sub figure {
    my ( $twig, $figure ) = @_;

    # Find all children of type label (would there really be more than 1??)
    foreach my $label ($figure->children('label')) {
        # Replace the label with its chidren nodes
        $label->replace_with($label->cut_children);

        # Find the caption and place 4 spaces before it
        if (my $caption = $figure->first_child('caption')) {
            my $some_whitespace = XML::Twig::Elt->new('#PCDATA' => '    ');
            $some_whitespace->paste(before => $caption);
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
<xml>
<fig id="fig6_4">
<label><xref ref-type="page" id="page_54"/>[Figure 4]</label>
<caption>The Klein Sexual Orientation Grid</caption>
</fig>
</xml>
```